# How to import parent/child objects in Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails, elasticsearch-model

I'm using the gems elasticsearch-rails and elasticsearch-model in my Rails app. I'm using [this integration test](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/blob/master/elasticsearch-model/test/integration/active_record_associations_parent_child.rb) as a template for setting up my mappings and such before importing existing data, which has the same basic association between the parent and child models.

I know the integration test works because of the callbacks and that it sets the parent id in those callbacks.

I would like to import existing Questions and Answers. It doesn't seem like it's enough to just call `Questions.import` and `Answers.import`. I get the questions, but I don't get any answers in my Elasticsearch store. I'd like to know how to import the Answers objects with the appropriate parent mapping. Can anyone give me any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question in case someone else is wondering the same thing.

You can pass something to transform the data as you import it:

```
transform = lambda do |a|
  {index: {_id: a.id, _parent: a.author_id, data: a.__elasticsearch__.as_indexed_json}}
end

Article.import transform: transform
```

The `elasticsearch-model` gem has more documentation here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/blob/ded20356920802c35d258756113acfd95b25ade6/elasticsearch-model/lib/elasticsearch/model/importing.rb